# React promise to end of useState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I am using context function and I calling the function on other js file. But setThreeImdf is useState function.

Context function;

```
     const [threeImdf, setThreeImdf] = useState({});

     const createMap = (ref, width, height) => {
          const display_point = map.venue.features[0].properties.display_point.coordinates;
          const threeImdf = new ThreeImdf(
            ref,
            width,
            height,
            map,
            display_point
          );
          window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            threeImdf.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
          });
          threeImdf.showLayer([0]);
          setThreeImdf(threeImdf);
        });
      };
```

Home.js useEffect function

```
const { map, createMap, threeImdf } = useContext(MapContext);

    useEffect( async () => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(map)) {
          createMap(mapRef, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
          const data = threeImdf.getGrouppedObjectsByLayer(currentFloor);
          const layers = threeImdf.getOrdinalsNumber();
          setFloorCount(layers);
          setCategories(data);
        }
      }, []);
```

But I run context function in useEffect, return to me threeImdf not found. I would like to wait setThreeImdf hook's end. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create Context

```
const Context = React.createContext(MapContext);
```

The Context was visible, you need to wrap the component in:

```
<Context.Provide>
   //You component
</Context.Provider>
```